# Поднятие бэкапа Wordpress на локал xampp

Tags: wordpress, xampp

У меня есть папка бэкапа вордпресса с папками : cron, db, dns, mail, pam, user_dir, vesta, web. Во всех туториалах бэкапа совсем другие файлы и папки с префиксом wp- 
В папке db есть файл sql (24mb). Создаю таблицу и пытаюсь сделать импорт, пишет Incorrect format parameter. Пожалуйста, объясните как с этого поднять wp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти  "папки" к ВП не имеют отношения. Возможно в `web` или его подкаталогах есть файлы ВП. Но толку от этого по сути не много.

Прежде всего нужно разобраться с тем, что в sql-файле и правильно импортировать в базу.
После найти в ней старый домен и пути(!) к файлам  выше [document_root](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php). (В помошь [описание базы](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database%20Description))

Сам же дистрибутив ВП стоит скачать с оф сайта https://ru.wordpress.org/releases/ посмотреть структуру, найти её у себя и развернуть в соответствии с тем как они находились в архиве относительно  каталога прописанного в [document_root](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) (возможно, что сайт был в подкаталоге).

А после того, как база будет импортирована и файлы ВП восстановлены - воспользоваться скриптом https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ и ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО заменить вначале пути, а потом домен, обращая внимание на слеши, наличие `www`, `@` и другие разных вхождений.

В будущем для миграции использовать спец. плагины. См подробнее [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Comment: Плюсанул. Только насчет ghjgbcfyyjuj не понял)

Comment: @KAGGDesign не торопися :)